# No puedo imprimir código PHP

Tags: php

Tengo un archivo TXT donde almaceno todos los mensajes y incluso los códigos pero el problema es al tratar de leer un código PHP me lo imprime directamente.

```
<?php
$file=fopen("mensajes.txt", 'r');
while(!feof($file))
{
$nombre = fgets($file);
$name = str_replace("DMA", "<b>[ADMIN]</b>",$nombre);
if(strpos($nombre, "DMA") !== false){
echo $name."<br>";
}else{
$name = str_replace("<","[",$name);
$name = str_replace(">","]",$name);
$name = str_replace("(font color=","<font color=",$name);
$name = str_replace("(/font)", "</font>", $name);
$name = str_replace(")",">",$name);
echo $name."<br>";
}}
fclose($file);
?>
```

Con cualquier código JavaScript me lo ejecuta perfectamente pero cuando intento con PHP me lo da directamente.

Comment: Para que se ejecute el código php, tienes dos formas: Si es a través del navegador, tienes que tener un servidor web (apache, iis, nginx, etc) y el proyecto debe estar dentro del directorio de publicación del mismo (htdocs, www, wwwroot, etc según el webserver que estes usando). Y si es un script, pues, invocarlo de la forma `ruta_del_ejecutable_php ruta_del_script/script.php`

Comment: Emm pero hay alguna forma de llamar al archivo por javascript?

Comment: No entiendo bien el problema. Te refieres a que en el archivo mensajes.txt puedes tener un código PHP y quieres que se ejecute línea a línea? Y además haciendo reemplazos en el código? Me da que deberías utilizar algo como `require` de PHP...

Comment: lo que digo que el archivo php lea el txt y la linea la interprete como si estuviera siendo parte de su codigo

Comment: si uso require siempre se ejecutaria ... no quiero que se ejecute si no esta en el archivo

Comment: Suena a que se quiere ejecutar el contenido del archivo txt, si es un código PHP. Ahí se necesitaría utilizar algo como `eval`, pero no está recomendado. Si es lo que quiere entonces sería mejor evaluar el código del txt y ver si se puede hacer de otro modo, usando namespaces por ej...